# Equivalent of the French SACEM in the USA?

Tags: copyright

In France, you can pay a yearly fee to an organisation called ["SACEM"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9_des_auteurs,_compositeurs_et_%C3%A9diteurs_de_musique) and use copyrighted works to make profit in various ways.

Is there an equivalent in the USA?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are equivalent rights clearinghouse organizations in the U.S. The most prominent are ASCAP and BMI. These organizations collect royalties (including mechanical license fees) for muscial works in much the same way that SACEM does in France. ASCAP and BMI also collect royalties for SACEM artists when their works are performed in the U.S. and vice versa through reciprocal agreements.

It's worth clarifying that you are not paying a subscription fee to the organization, exactly; you are still paying an artist's royalty. The clearinghouse just streamlines the process and manages the payments.

Comment: That's great! Could you add a couple of links to your answer in order to help me and other potential users go through signup processes. One could google those but with initials it's always hit or miss

Comment: ASCAP and BMI doesn't collect mechanical royalties!